# Null Pointer Exception not caught in java dialogue

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to receive input from a java dialog and I can't seem to catch the `NullPointerException` when the box is closed, can anyone help?

```
private static final String DEFAULTNAME = "Player001"; 

public class Player implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Player(String Pname,int Pscore)
    {
         name = Pname;
         score = Pscore;
    }
}

    try
    {
        person = new Player(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name"),0);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        person = new Player(DEFAULTNAME,0);
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        person = new Player(DEFAULTNAME,0);
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution or is there a way of making the dialog unable to close?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are better off checking the name for invalid values before adding it in

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name");
if(name == null || name.equals(""))name = DEFAULTNAME;
person = new Player(name,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't "catch" a NPE like you're doing. Get the String from the user, see if it == null, and then if so use the default player name.  In pseudo code:

```
call JOptionPane and get player name
If player name is null
  create new Player with default name
else
  create new Player with the user-entered name.
```

No need for try/catch here.

Another way to solve it is to let your Player constructor accept a null String and change it to default:

```
public Player(String Pname,int Pscore)
{
     name = (Pname == null || Pname.trim().isEmpty()) ? DEFAULT_NAME : Pname;
     score = Pscore;
}
```